# Cannot select a column from a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, ora-00904

I made this query that i need but i need only one column from the result. So it goes like this:

```
select SWDATECREATED from 
      (select * from MBR_INST_PRODUCTS
       inner join MBR_SUBSCRIBERS 
       on MBR_INST_PRODUCTS.SWOBJECTID = MBR_SUBSCRIBERS.SWSUBRID 
       where MBR_SUBSCRIBERS.SWSUBRID = 54501928
       and SWINSTPRODID = 1433193947);
```

If i run the select within the brackets it`s good.
But if i try to select only a specific column from that result set i get error ORA-00904.
I checked the error already but all the columns are written correctly.
How can i select only SWDATECREATED from the select?

Here`s my error:
ORA-00904: "SWDATECREATED": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 8

Thank you for your time.

Comment: . . You need to be clear about what query works and what doesn't work.  I'm confused.

Comment: What happens if you just run the subquery by itself, but instead of using `*` you select only `SWDATECREATED`?

Comment: You say "All the columns are written correctly" but I only see one column "Written" the rest of the columns selection leaves us troubleshooters blind as we have no idea what is being selected in `*`. Be more explicit in your SQL and perhaps the issue and it's solution will present itself.

Comment: What is in brackets:

select * from MBR_INST_PRODUCTS
       inner join MBR_SUBSCRIBERS 
       on MBR_INST_PRODUCTS.SWOBJECTID = MBR_SUBSCRIBERS.SWSUBRID 
       where MBR_SUBSCRIBERS.SWSUBRID = 54501928
       and SWINSTPRODID = 1433193947
gives me a result row
but from that row i only want to get the column SWDATECREATED

Comment: @VictorG - but you have two columns with that name in the result set, right?

Answer (score 3):

You basically have a situation like this, where you have the same column names in both tables (though presumably you have more columns than this):

```
create table MBR_INST_PRODUCTS (SWINSTPRODID, SWOBJECTID, SWDATECREATED) as
select 1433193947, 54501928, date '2018-01-01' from dual;

create table MBR_SUBSCRIBERS (SWSUBRID, SWDATECREATED) as
select 54501928, date '2018-02-28' from dual;

select * from MBR_INST_PRODUCTS
inner join MBR_SUBSCRIBERS 
on MBR_INST_PRODUCTS.SWOBJECTID = MBR_SUBSCRIBERS.SWSUBRID 
where MBR_SUBSCRIBERS.SWSUBRID = 54501928
and SWINSTPRODID = 1433193947;

SWINSTPRODID SWOBJECTID SWDATECREATED         SWSUBRID SWDATECREATED      
------------ ---------- ------------------- ---------- -------------------
  1433193947   54501928 2018-01-01 00:00:00   54501928 2018-02-28 00:00:00
```

In the result set you have all the columns from both tables, including those with the same name. The client (SQL Developer in this case) is displaying the original column names, but some might change them to be unique.

When you try to use that query as an inline view the names have to be unique, and Oracle is implicitly adding something internally to make them unique; it doesn't really matter what or how it decides. When you do

```
select SWDATECREATED from ( .. that query ... )
```

neither internal name for those two columns in the inline view now matches the one you expect to see, so you get an ORA-00904. That identifier does *not* exist in the inline view.

You don't need a subquery to get just that column, but you have to specify *which* of the two columns you want - otherwise you'll get an ORA-00918 since Oracle can't guess which one you meant:

```
select MBR_INST_PRODUCTS.SWDATECREATED from MBR_INST_PRODUCTS
inner join MBR_SUBSCRIBERS 
on MBR_INST_PRODUCTS.SWOBJECTID = MBR_SUBSCRIBERS.SWSUBRID 
where MBR_SUBSCRIBERS.SWSUBRID = 54501928
and SWINSTPRODID = 1433193947;

SWDATECREATED      
-------------------
2018-01-01 00:00:00

select MBR_SUBSCRIBERS.SWDATECREATED from MBR_INST_PRODUCTS
inner join MBR_SUBSCRIBERS 
on MBR_INST_PRODUCTS.SWOBJECTID = MBR_SUBSCRIBERS.SWSUBRID 
where MBR_SUBSCRIBERS.SWSUBRID = 54501928
and SWINSTPRODID = 1433193947;

SWDATECREATED      
-------------------
2018-02-28 00:00:00
```

If you have another reason to use a subquery then you either need to specify which table you want that column from in the same way, optionally including other columns; or include both columns but give them unique aliases. You will then be able to refer to the alises in the outer query.

---

It's often considered bad practice to use `*`, particularly in a subquery, partly because it can cause more work than necessary to be done, partly because you can be tripped up by table changes between code runs, and partly because it can cause this sort of confusion.

It's better to explicitly name the columns you want; and to prefix *all* columns with the table they are coming from (or a table alias) even if they are unique, so you and anyone who has to maintain the code can follow it more easily; I had to guess which table to put the `SWINSTPRODID` column in. It's also safer - just in case a new column is added to a table later which makes it non-unique.

Comment: Wow, you just went the whole 9 yards :) I really appreciate you took time to explain me the inner workings and i really do understand now this and maybe more. Thank you very much man !! The internet is great.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use that as columnname in the query:

```
select SWDATECREATED from MBR_INST_PRODUCTS
   inner join MBR_SUBSCRIBERS 
   on MBR_INST_PRODUCTS.SWOBJECTID = MBR_SUBSCRIBERS.SWSUBRID 
   where MBR_SUBSCRIBERS.SWSUBRID = 54501928
   and SWINSTPRODID = 1433193947;
```

Comment: I already tried this SurfMan but i get ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined.

Comment: @VictorG - then it exists in both tables, and you need to prefix it with the table name you want to actually get the value from.

Comment: What @AlexPoole says: use the table name: MBR_INST_PRODUCTS.SWDATECREATED (If both columns contain the same data, it doesn't really matter, but you should be careful picking the correct one)

Comment: That`s right, it is in both tables. I prefixed it and now i get the correct answer.
Thanks guys !!!